Log message concerning i915 appears for the first time after kernel upgrade on Xubuntu 22.04.4
A few days ago the kernel was upgraded to version 6.8.40-generic on my Xubuntu 22.04.4 system. While browsing the internet with Chrome, the following log message appeared for the first time:
i915 0000:00:02.0: Using 39-bit DMA addresses

The system is equipped with Intel XE Graphics.
What does this message mean please?
Thank you.
